# Is there any way to send firebase OTP SMS authentication through web

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase , I want to know that is there any way to send firebase OTP SMS from Laravel backend ?
I am using Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

When using Firebase Authentication, signing in the user (including requested an OTP via SMS) always has to happen from the client-side code. So while you can request the SMS OTP from client-side JavaScript as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone), you can't send the SMS OTP from server-side PHP/Laravel.